# Macro to autofill N number of cells(rows/columns) based on a value in a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Consider the following example:

[image]

Consider that i have in the "sheet 1" the table with the columns Country and Food with its values.

In the sheet 2, i have two columns named Country#1 and Food#1. The macro i already have (credits to @sktneer), needs to autofill the Food#1 cell that is associated with the right text in Country#1 cell, via the drop down list.

Example: When i select "Madrid" in Country#1, it needs to autofill the Food#1 with the text "Tapas and tortillas".

The code for this is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Set wsSource = Sheets("Sheet1")     'Source sheet which contains a table of countries and their food
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then
        If Application.CountIf(wsSource.Columns(1), Target.Value) > 0 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            r = Application.Match(Target.Value, wsSource.Columns(1), 0)
            Target.Offset(0, 1) = wsSource.Cells(r, 2)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

My question is: Can this code be scaled to a greater number of columns, for the exact same problem?

Here's a preview of an example:

[image]

Sorry if this question is extensive, but my ultimate goal here is to compare both codes ( the one i have and this example ), to learn how to scale to N number of rows and N number of columns.

Best regards,
Luís

Comment: The short answer is - yes, easily. Your clue to being able to figure this out for yourself is already in the code dude - "Target.Offset(0, 1) = wsSource.Cells(r, 2)". Technically your just posting code from another question and havent "tried" this foryourself. For the most part I gave you the answer, you just need to understand what it is doing. Once you understand that you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

Place the following code on Sheet2 Module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Set wsSource = Sheets("Sheet1")     'Source sheet which contains a table of countries and their food
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target <> "" Then
        If Application.CountIf(wsSource.Columns(1), Target.Value) > 0 Then
            r = Application.Match(Target.Value, wsSource.Columns(1), 0)
            wsSource.Range("B" & r & ":E" & r).Copy Target.Offset(0, 1)
            Target.Offset(0, 1) = wsSource.Cells(r, 2)
        End If
    Else
        Target.Resize(1, 5).ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems overly complicated when all you're trying to do is essentially a vlookup. Here's a basic formula which could be applied if your data is in the upper left column, and assuming the column order matches. `=INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1048576,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,TRUE),MATCH(B$1,Sheet2!$1:$1,FALSE))`

Alternatively, using VBA when setting value to be more dynamic like this....

```
 Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), Target.Offset(0, Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsSource.Rows(1)) + 1)).Value = _
            Range(wsSource.Cells(r, 2), wsSource.Cells(r, Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsSource.Rows(1)))).Value
```